# getting data out of Firebase OnChange method

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-storage

Hello I'm developping an Android App , using Firebase , I have a problem while trying to get the data out from the firebase onchange method It keeps returning null out of the method like if the data is only available inside the method and null outside .
To be more explicit , I have an array of data containing some names and a url reference to a picture in the firebase storage so I get the array and I put the data in textviews etc (all of this is happening inside onchange cause outside data is null ) and when I want to download the pictures I need to use another firebase method when I do it I get this error I think it s because there is an async method inside another the error says something about maximum thread is reached 128 or something like this , here's the code

```
 ideasListFireRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            HashMap<String, HashMap> ideasList = (HashMap<String, HashMap>) dataSnapshot.getValue();//getting list
            idsList = new ArrayList<>( ideasListFire.keySet()); //list of IDs of picture to get from firebase storage                               //method to get pictures from firebase storage
            imagesTab = new HashMap<>();
            while (i < idsList.size()) {
                final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

                StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(ideasListFire.get(idsList.get(i)).get("mainPic").toString());
                storageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                        // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        imagesTab.put(idsList.get(i), bmp);
                        // testim.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });
```

this code give me the error of the threads problem 
and the other code where the methods are separated gives null in Ids list cause the idsList is null out of the onDataChange method
Thank you so much for helping and excuse my english mistakes =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the data outside of the onChanged() method. You can save it in an ArrayList and use an iterator to get them out. Here is an example using the onDataChanged method:

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> returns = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

        while(returns.iterator().hasNext())
        {
            Alarm al = returns.iterator().next().getValue(Alarm.class);
            GlobalData.totalAlarms.add(al);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```